# Mapping NHibernate with confORM

Tags: model-view-controller, nhibernate, mapping, many-to-many, conform

I have 2 classes (summarized for brevity) :

```
public class Product : Entity<Guid>
{      
    ...    
    public virtual IList<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }          
    public Product(){Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();}    
}
```

and

```
public partial class Ingredient : Entity<int>
{
    ...
    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public Ingredient(){Products = new List<Product>();}
}
```

They have a ManyToMany relationship, and I want to do:

- if I delete one ingredient, the product is not removed but only the ingredient for his list.
- if I delete one product, the ingredients are all without being deleted.

I did this map, but I can't get this to work.

```
orm.ManyToMany<Product, Ingredient>();
orm.Cascade<Product, Ingredient>(CascadeOn.DeleteOrphans);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it.
This is the way I could resolve this, in case to help someone more:

```
        orm = new ObjectRelationalMapper();
        mapper = new Mapper(orm);
        //...

        mapper.Class<Ingredient>(c =>
        {
           /* ...[MAP OTHERS PROPERTY]...*/
           // Many to many relationship in One side
            c.Bag(p => p.Products, pm => pm.Inverse(false), rel => rel.ManyToMany());
        });

       // Many to many relationship in other side
       orm.ManyToMany<Product, Ingredient>();
```